window function does not use index
I have a query that uses a window function like this:
SELECT 
         stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates.date AS date
         , stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates.client_id AS client_id
         ,coalesce (
              stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates.user_amount 
            , first_value (stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates.user_amount) 
                over (partition by 
                        client_id
                      , user_amount_group
                      order by 
                        date asc
                    )
         ) AS user_amount

FROM stage.stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates;

It's doing an expensive sort step on disk https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/gc1dcechdd4h45f5 , so I tried to add an index:
CREATE INDEX idx_stage_account_client_user_amount_date_asc
ON stage.stage_account_060_exploded_all_dates (client_id, user_amount_group, date asc);

However, The planner does not use the index https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/h7813c3d3115f69g, unless I use the set enable_sort = off parameter.
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/3af504022g75de6d
Can I hint the planner to use the index in another way?
Or should I try to add   set enable_sort = off before the query and than set enable_sort = on just after the query again? (if the scope of the set enable_sort = off is just the connection/session the latter might not be needed?)
I'm using PostgreSQL 15.
